# Highstock json data not showing

Tags: php, json, highcharts

Hey guys I am having trouble loading my data into the highstock charts.

My json.php calls on a sample MySQL database and looks something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*1000 AS timestamp,value from sample") or die('Could not query');

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    echo 'Test';

    $first = true;
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){

        if($first) {
            $first = false;
        } else {
            echo ',';
        }
        $json_str = json_encode($row, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        echo $json_str;
    }
    if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)){
    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback. '('.$json_str.');';
    }
} else {
    echo '[]';
}

mysql_close($db);
```

My index.htm which calls the Json.php is from the sample highstock template I just merely changed the getJson to match with my reference. Here is the code. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Test'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'Test',
                data : data,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                shadow : true,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, my json is parsed in this manner:

> Test[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,4],[1368177426000,11],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,14],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,15],[1370899026000,12],[1378826226000,7],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,3],[1370899026000,6],[1370899026000,0],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,15],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,14],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,22],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,6],[1370899026000,6],[1370899026000,6],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,14],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,15],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,3],[1370899026000,6],[1370899026000,0],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,7],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,11],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,8],[1370899026000,15],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,14],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,12],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,13],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,4],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,22],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,9],[1370899026000,10],[1370899026000,5],[1370899026000,7]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? what is the problem with your current solution? please clarify your question.

Comment: For security and performance reasons you should switch from mysql_* functions to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Your problem is that the `echo 'Test'` line makes your output invalid JSON. The chart will not show if the JSON that you load is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. Cshaprley, I am trying to get highchart to display my json output in its chart form. Basically, I am pulling data from a MySQL database and visualizing it with HighCharts.

Comment: likeitlikeit, could you elaborate further? I've removed the echo line but its still not showing. Even with the echo line my json.php is able to view the data but my chart cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing with

```
[]
```

Highstock fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/areaspline/

Data of that fiddle:  http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I've tried enclosing the data with the brackets but its still not showing. I checked around and apparently some guy said converting the values to integers will help but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database and take look at very simple example with json_encode:

```
    tmp = array();

$tmp[] = array('A',5);
$tmp[] = array('B',6);
$tmp[] = array('C',1);
$tmp[] = array('D',2);
$rows = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($tmp); $i++)
{
    $row['name'] = $tmp[$i][0];
    $row['data'] = array($tmp[$i][1]);
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows);
```

Highcharts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                        },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

            $.getJSON("datavotecolum.php", function(json) {
          console.log(json);
                options.series = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options,function(chart){

               console.log(chart.series);
               });
            });



        });
```